# Not able to see the label of the Api names

Tags: pagination, salesforce, admin, apex, visualforce

SelectedFields is the list of the fields having API Name and  itr the iterative variable and similarly rec is the iterator variable for the records So whenever I am using {!itr}
in the facet then it will print API name and If do not use facet then it will print label of the fields how to fix this??

```
<apex:repeat value="{!selectedFields}" var="itr">
                <apex:column value="{!rec[itr]}">
                   <apex:facet name="header">
                       <apex:commandLink action="{!sortByColumn}" reRender="recPage">{!itr}
                            <apex:param name="Names" value="{!itr}" assignTo="{!sortingValues}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                </apex:column>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use [`$SobjectType`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_globals_objecttype.htm) to get the field label, something like `{!$ObjectType.Account.fields[itr].label}`?

Alternatively in apex build a `Map<String, String>` where key is the api name and value is the label. Or you can even iterate over list of field tokens, not strings. `sObject` class supports a dynamic `get` with field token as param so same trick should work in VF and you can get label out of a token too.

Comment: Okay but the problem is How can I give the dynamic name for object {!$ObjectType.Account.fields[itr].label} it will only work for Account Object

Comment: You haven't even clicked the link, have you? 1st code example is `$ObjectType[sObjectName].fields[fieldName].Type`. Except you need label, not type.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah! `{!$ObjectType.Account.fields[itr].label}` It is the way to get the Label from the API name of Objects and For the dynamic objects. We can use this `{!$ObjectType[sObject].fields[itr].label}` as it will take out the label from the API names.